# In Elixir, how to fix a nested list

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, I have the following list:

`[ :juridical_person_document, [re_developments: [[properties: [[re_development: [:re_developer]]]]]], :legal_address ]`

And my desired output would be this:

`[ :juridical_person_document,  re_developments: [properties: [re_development:  [:re_developer]]], :legal_address ]`

In other words, I want to remove the unnecessary square brackets. How can I achieve that?

I am aware that this can be achieved with recursion, but I didn't figure out how yet.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the second element of the “desired output” cannot be specified as above, it’s the list `[re_developments: [properties: [re_development:  [:re_developer]]]]`. Yours won’t even compile.

Comment: Do you control the generating code? Fixing it there would be better if possible.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I just struck out the “recommend `Macro.postwalk/2` on SO” from my to-do list, now I consider my [tag:elixir] SO mission completed, as I did for [tag:ruby] when recommended [flip-flop](https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2018/02/22/flip-flop-real-application). Please don’t ruin my happiness with correct suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of a sudden, [`Macro.postwalk/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#postwalk/2) would work here.

```elixir
Macro.postwalk(input, fn [[x]] -> [x]; x -> x end)

[
  :juridical_person_document,
  [re_developments: [properties: [re_development: [:re_developer]]]],
  :legal_address
]
```

This hack uses the fact that lists, atoms, and tuples of size two are all valid AST.

Comment: Thanks, the trick works. I can't upvote you since I am a freshmember.